# Launching Python script with arguments from VBA in Outlook

Tags: python, vba, outlook

I'm trying to trigger a Python script when an email is moved to a certain folder.

The idea is to set up a rule in Outlook that moves an email to a specific folder when it contains certain keywords, then have a VBA script launch the Python script with arguments when a new item is added to a folder. I am following [this guide.](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/itemadd-macro/)

```vb
Option Explicit
Private objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Private WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim objWatchFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objWatchFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objItems = objWatchFolder.Items

    Set objWatchFolder = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    MsgBox "Message subject: " & Item.Subject & vbcrlf & "Message sender: " & Item.SenderName &" (" & Item.SenderEmailAddress & ")"
    Dim subject As Item.subject
    Shell("""C:\Path\to\python.exe"" ""C:\Path\With Spaces\script.py """ & subject)
    Set Item = Nothing
End Sub
```

Previously, the following worked after declaring the subject variable using `Dim subject As Item.subject`:

`Shell("""C:\path\to\python.exe"" ""C:\Path\With Spaces\To\Script\Hello.py """ & subject)`

Now I am getting a compile error

> user-defined type not defined.

This error occurs on the `Dim subject As Item.subject` line.

When I try to pass the email's subject to the Python script via:

`Shell("""C:\path\to\python.exe"" ""C:\Path\With Spaces\To\Script\Hello.py """ & Item.subject)`

It does not crash, but it looks like the Python script never runs.

When I do:

`Shell("""C:\path\to\python.exe"" ""C:\Path\With Spaces\To\Script\Hello.py "" & Item.subject")`

It passes `&` and `Item.subject` as string arguments - the email's subject stored in Item.subject is not passed, but the literal string "Item.subject".

Why would `Dim subject As Item.subject` now cause an error and how do I pass the email's subject as an argument to my Python script?

Comment: Pictures of code are not useful. Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Tragamor: Thanks, I edited the question to get rid of the screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume your issue is with incorrect double quote assignments and spacing for calling the python code. I would also assume the subject can have spaces in it so should be enclosed in double quotes which therefore gives rise to (assuming I have the nomenclature correct for the call):

> """C:\Path\to\python.exe"" ""C:\Path\With Spaces\script.py"" """ & Item.subject & """"

You can use the Debug.Print to check the string is as expected before the call to run the python script. Disclaimer: I haven't used python scripts so this is untested

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    With Application.Outlook
        Set ObjItems = .GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        Dim strFunc As String: strFunc = """C:\Path\to\python.exe"" ""C:\Path\With Spaces\script.py"" """ & Item.subject & """"
        Debug.Print strFunc
        Shell strFunc, vbMinimizedNoFocus
    End If
End Sub
```